# How to fetch pathParam value in useEffect in React JS

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, use-effect, path-parameter

When I pass the teamName hard coded the correct results are showing but want to pass teamName from url using pathParam

**Code:**

```
export const TeamPage = () => {

    const [team, setTeam] = useState({matches :[]});

    
    const {teamName} = useParams();

    useEffect(
        ()=>{
            const fetchMatches = async() =>{
               
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8787/team/${teamName}');
                const data = await response.json();
                setTeam(data);
            };
            fetchMatches();
        },[]

    );
    console.log(teamName);
    if(!team || !team.teamName){
        return <h1>Team not found</h1>
    }

    return (
        <div className="TeamPage">
            <h1>{team.teamName}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the url isn't providing the proper data... Can you validate the URL includes the team name with correct format?

Comment: @silencedogood when replace the **${teamName}** with actual value (e.g - **ABC** ) then correct results shown without any errors.

Comment: I understand that. Which is why I believe it's very likely that the `{teamName}` variable isn't being set correctly by the query string within the URL.

Comment: Thanks @silencedogood The **undefine** teamName in url is resolved by cleaning the browser. I didn't find any issue when I have changed the browser then, after  just by clean the cookies from chrome the issues has been disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think you are using wrong syntax, it should be:

```
const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8787/team/${teamName}`);
```

so `` instead of ''